# Unable to apply datediff(d1,d2) if value flag in col1=1

Tags: amazon-web-services, calculated-columns, calculated-field, amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

In quicksight I want to calculate the Datediff only in the rows where value flag for cancellation=1(True) and add the output in new column on same row level, for row where cancellation=0, do not perform datediff

**My Quicksight query - this isn't working - Need Help with this
`ifelse(cancellation='1',dateDiff({upload_dt},{billed_date}),'null')`**

**My excel query - THIS IS WORKING
`=IF(D2=1,(B2-C2),"null")`**

Answer (score 0):

In the date diff function you're not specifying the date granularity.
For years do ifelse(cancellation='1',dateDiff({upload_dt},{billed_date},'YYYY'),'null')
For days do ifelse(cancellation='1',dateDiff({upload_dt},{billed_date},'DD'),'null')

More information is available here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/dateDiff-function.html